# How to fix count with group by

Tags: sql

i have sql query like this,

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(`op_total`) AS int) as total
FROM `dashboard_sales`
WHERE `op_status` IN ('settlement', 'capture') AND
      `order_date` between '2018-01-01' and '2019-06-30' AND
      `order_status` IN ('Ordered', 'Validated','Awaiting Packing','Packing Process','Ready to Ship','Shipped','Completed')
```

and this is the result,

first image:

[image]

but because there is duplication of data in some order_id so the results are bigger than the original

and i have make another query using group by like this,

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(`op_total`) AS int) as total 
FROM `dashboard_sales` 
WHERE 
`op_status` IN ('settlement', 'capture')  
AND `order_date` between '2018-01-01' and '2019-06-30'
AND `order_status` IN ('Ordered', 'Validated','Awaiting Packing','Packing Process','Ready to Ship','Shipped','Completed')
GROUP BY  `order_id`
```

but the result is like this,

second image:

[image]

how to make like first image when i use group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a subquery on top of your query

```
select sum(total) as total
from
(
SELECT CAST(SUM(op_total) AS int) as total 
FROM dashboard_sales
WHERE op_status IN ('settlement', 'capture')  
AND order_date between '2018-01-01' and '2019-06-30'
AND order_status IN ('Ordered', 'Validated','Awaiting Packing','Packing Process','Ready to Ship','Shipped','Completed')
GROUP BY  order_id
)A
```